# How to extract domain name from this DNS message?

Tags: dns, tcpdump, packet-capture, netfilter

Example  code to sniff packet is http://opensourceforu.efytimes.com/2011/02/capturing-packets-c-program-libpcap using another_callback function(),when type :

```
[root@localhost tcpsnip]# ./sniffer udp

Packet Count: 1
Recieved Packet Size: 76
Payload:
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  . )  .  . /  .  . E  .  . 
> : g @  . @  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
.  .  .  . 5  . *  .  . C  .  .  .  .  .  . 
.  .  .  .  .  . w w w  . f a c e b o 
o k  . c o m  .  .  .  .  . 
Packet Count: 2
Recieved Packet Size: 76
Payload:
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  . )  .  . /  .  . E  .  . 
> : h @  . @  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
.  .  .  . 5  . *  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
.  .  .  .  .  . w w w  . f a c e b o 
o k  . c o m  .  .  .  .  .
```

here,how can I extract domain name(www.facebook.com) from all these packets(c language). thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

By writing code to parse whatever link-layer protocol you have (use `pcap_datalink()` to find out the link-layer header format value; see [the "Link-Layer Header Types" page](http://www.tcpdump.org/linktypes.html) for what they mean), [IPv4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc791) or [IPv6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2460), [UDP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc768), and [DNS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035).

Or perhaps by forgetting about writing it in C and using [Scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/) instead.  *Capturing* packets is relatively easy; *dissecting* packets is hard, which is why tcpdump has about 750 lines of code, and Wireshark has about 5700 lines of code, just to parse DNS (that doesn't count the lines of code to parse all the protocols underneath DNS).  Writing code to parse packets is a significant amount of work; using somebody else's code is a lot less work.

Comment: thank you for the answer and  suggestion. I will go through the link.